Normal approximation for posterior distribution
I am reading the example 4.3.3 of "The Bayesian Choice" by Christian P. Robert and I was wondering if it is possible to obtain a normal approximation in this case to estimate the posterior. I know that the posterior has a closed form
$$
\begin{align*}
            \pi(N = n | n_{11}) & = \frac{ \displaystyle  \frac{\binom{5}{ n_{11} } \binom{N-5}{5-n_{11}}}{\binom{N}{5}}  \cdot \frac{1}{15} }{ \displaystyle \sum_{i = 36}^{50} \frac{\binom{5}{n_{11}} \binom{i-n_1}{5-n_{11}} }{\binom{i}{5}} \cdot    \frac{1}{15} }
        \end{align*}
$$
but what would happen with a normal approximation? In this case we are estimating $N$, an integer, how would the normal approximation make sense? It would help me to obtain some bibliographical references on this. Greetings.

Thank you for reading my book! I would not consider a Normal approximation to the Hypergeometric distribution, as it is discrete. Especially since $N$ is an unknown quantity, hence not necessarily very large.

In addition, I am unsure the Normal approximation would help given the constraint on $N$ imposed by observing $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_{11}$

The normal distribution wouldn't really make sense in this case because the normal distribution is a continuous distribution and your target posterior distribution is a discrete distribution over the integers.

For large $n$, you can approximate the binomial CDF pretty well with a normal approximation based on the mean and variance.
